# Models in Computer Networks

Tags: network-programming

TCP/IP  model  uses  the  seven  layers  of  the  OSI  models  by  putting  the session,   presentation   and   application   layer   into   a   single   one   i:e APPLICATION. What  other MODELS  exist  that  uses  the  OSI  reference  model  layers  in  practical implementation.

I've found TCP/IP model,n need more models that uses OSI layers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different models in the literature. Various standards organizations, companies, academics and authors created their own reference models

There's an excellent [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite#Layer_names_and_number_of_layers_in_the_literature) on Wikpedia that compares the models to each other. Here's a screenshot for convenience:

[image]

Comment: Yes this was what I wanted .Thanks :)

Comment: But I can't find these models whole explanation in Internet

Answer (score 0):

The TCP/IP model *predates* the OSI model. The OSI model only applies to the OSI protocol stack, despite the fervency with which it was marketed in the 1989s and is still for some reason taught today, and it doesn't apply properly to that either, and (b) is obsolete.